# resources/assets/js/app.js code is running for all routes using Vue Laravel

Tags: vue-component, laravel-5.4

I am learning **[Broadcasting using Vue according to this article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#presence-channels)**

it's Laravel, Pusher and npm

**I have below code in resources/assets/js/app.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        messages: []
    },
    methods: {
        addMessage(message) {
            this.messages.push(message);
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get(window.Laravel.AppUrl + "/Messages").then(response => {
           this.messages = response.data; 
        });
    }
});

Vue.component('chat-composer', require('./components/ChatComposer.vue'));
```

**Below is the tag in blade**

```
<chat-composer v-on:messagesent="addMessage"></chat-composer>
```

Everything is working fine...Just the problem is the above app.js code is running every time on all routes.

I was making sample code in Angular Js and there was option to make Controllers, Models and Views.

Is there any way to run the code such that the above route works for particualr route only?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `axios` in the `created` method of your root Vue instance. It's going to call that on every single page that loads the app. Move stuff that is only required for certain features into the components that need it.

If you want different components to appear on different pages you can only render the components you need on the page, or look into using **Vue Router** on the client side.

Comment: Do we have any doc that explains which method should be used in which situation?

Comment: Read Vue's documentation. The `created` method is literally the first thing your Vue app will call when it's finished loading on a page. It's the location for any global code to be run.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS have controllers, models and views by which it tells how your applications should be structured, Vue JS is more adaptable in that sense. But coming back to your point, why that code runs every time: created block as the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) says:

> Called synchronously after the instance is created. At this stage, the instance has finished processing the options which means the following have been set up: data observation, computed properties, methods, watch/event callbacks.

So every time the vue component instance is created, code of it's `created` block get's executed. [Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) you can see different life cycle hooks and their execution order.

You have not provided more code, but as it seems from your comments, You have  more routes, so you can either put this code in the component specific to that route, [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components/ItemList.vue#L69) is an example of data being loaded in [beforeMount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount) block.

You can also use [Per-Route Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html), where you will have a `beforeEnter` block specific to that route.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // code here will be executed only for /foo route
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

You can check [vue-hackernews](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) for an sample small size vue application which demoes lot of it's features.

Comment: @Helper I have not tried it but you can check [this](https://fagray.github.io/vuejs2-laravel53-starter/), if you dont have vue routes you can use the approach of having it in relevant component only.

Comment: Laravel [routes](https://github.com/fagray/vuejs2-laravel53-starter/blob/master/routes/api.php) are more of API endpoints, as actual UI routes are [vue routes](https://github.com/fagray/vuejs2-laravel53-starter/blob/master/resources/assets/js/router.js).

Comment: Do we have any kind of documentation for your above statement? I am assuming that Laravel can be used for FrontEnd(in the form of blade) and Backend(api purpose). Please suggest.

Comment: @Helper Not sure of official documentation, but same thoughts are expressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39714705/1610034), and one more similar implementation of [laravel routes](https://github.com/mattstauffer/suggestive/blob/42946347555f9f514a5a6af9af15241753325c43/app/Http/routes.php) and [vue routes](https://github.com/mattstauffer/suggestive/blob/60232c77641d355f023570f805025d8d76b5ad72/resources/assets/js/routes.js) which I found in this [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/using-vue-router-with-laravel).

Comment: You can also check [this](http://taha-sh.com/blog/spa-with-vuejs-and-laravel-routing-basics) and [this](http://taha-sh.com/blog/spa-with-vuejs-and-laravel-preparing-categories-topics-api).