# Laravel and Vue JS Route

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

How can I use my laravel web.php's route('test.create') in Vue component?
Here's the web.php:

```html
Route::resource('/test', 'TestController');
```

But I want to access the url via route('test.create') and add it into the `<form>` in my Vue component.
Here's the Vue component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form action="{{route('test.create')}}" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <input type="text" id="location" class="form-control"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="number" id="age" class="form-control"> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> 
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'create',
  data: function(){
    return {
        msg: '',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39714705/5350773

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, what exactly is the problem that you are running into right now?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access `route()` it is a `Laravel helper function` it works only inside

> /resources/views/

Answer (score 0):

`route('test.create')` is a laravel function, it won't work from a vue component/javascript. You would need to pass the returned value to the vue component via the DOM (in your template/blade php files).

eg:

in your view.blade.php:

```
<your-component create-url="{{route('test.create')}}"></your-component>
```

in your Component.vue:

```
props: ['createUrl']
```

then you can use

```
<form action="{{createUrl}}" method="POST">
```